# Wait until ajax is done

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a code like this:

```
var links="";
function upload(file){
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append("image", file); // Append the file 
   // Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "http://someapi.com");
   xhr.onload = function() {
      // Big win!
      // The URL of the image is:         
        links += "[IMG]"+JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.original+"[/IMG]\n";                 
        //showResult(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.link);
   }
   // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
   // And now, we send the formdata
   xhr.send(fd);
}
function catchFiles(files){
    nfiles = files.length;
    //var links="";
    for(var i=0;i<nfiles;i++){
        upload(files[i]);
    }                       
}
function showResult(links){     
    document.getElementById('div_result').innerText = links;                    
}
```

What I want is how to wait until the catchFiles is done (upload done all file) after that, the showResult will be call.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: You need to listen for a ready state change.

Comment: Don't really understand hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the jQuery feature I mentioned (maybe I imagined it), so I came up with another answer:

Add the variable `ajaxcounter` and set it to the number of files you are going to send, you could count them in upload, but that might bring the risk that it reaches 0 before all request are started, you'd better hard-code the value, or if it is dynamically set store all the prepared XHRs in an array and send them when you know you have all.

Then do this in your upload function:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readystate == 4) {
        // Process the responseText
        ajaxDidFinish();
    }
}
```

And make this the `ajaxDidFinish` function:

```
function ajaxDidFinish() {
    ajaxCounter--;
    if(ajaxCounter == 0) {
        // All your requests should be ready now
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, I didn't test it.

Comment: Look like this solution will work, I'll try and feedback soon. Thank dude ;)

Answer (score 1):

When an XHR call is complete, it fires the `onreadystatechange` with `readyState` == 4. So you need to assign a function to that event, not `onload`:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){

        console.log(xhr.responseText);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is done with each file, my question is done when upload all file in for loop.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? I believe jQuery has something for that. @HanTran

Comment: @11684 If I replace the upload function with the jQuery, it's will provide the callback to catch when upload file is done, but I want to catch when for is done :(

Comment: Yes, but jQuery has a callback that executes when all AJAX calls are completed. (I'm not entirely sure about that, I'll check the docs.) @HanTran